# How to validate whether submitted form is empty?

Tags: php, validation, input

My form consists of different types of inputs.

Is there a way of checking if form has been submitted with any user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way of checking if an entire form is blank?
>
> Without checking each individual input?

In short. No there is not.

You could treat `$_POST` as an array and check each entry in a loop, but you must be aware of items that are automatically filled, like `$_POST['submit']` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Run the input through [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) - it will return empty array if there is no single value in the array. If there is a value, the array will be non-empty.

Keep in mind that this way even if just one checkbox is checked form will be considered non-empty.

Comment: This will also remove any values which evaluate to false, e.g. 0.

Answer (score -1):

To see if anything is present (either a text input, or at least a checkbox value=1) you might use:

```
strlen(join($_POST))
```

Obviously only if it's a POST form, and that's not a big help either if you have radio or select boxes with a default. Also the submit button may not add a string by itself (don't give it a name=).

Comment: Imploding all the input array can be resource-costly. It can be abused for malicious purposes, esp. if you expose the whole `$_POST` array.